# Python getting a variable to change as what it's assigned to changes

Tags: python

For example, if I say:

```
a = 50
b = 3 * a
a = 46
```

The value of b after this runs would still be `3 * 50` = 150. How would I assign b to equal `3 * a` such that when a changes, the value of b also changes, without me having to restate `b = 3 * a` again?

EDIT: I would have searched this up but I really wasn't sure how to word it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `b` into a function:

```
def b():
    return 3 * a
```

then use it by calling it, i.e. `b()`

Answer (score 3):

## With lambda function

You can create a [lambda function](http://www.secnetix.de/~olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk). But, it requires you to add empty parenthesis after each call of `b`.

```
>>> a = 50
>>> b = lambda: a * 3
>>> b
<function <lambda> at 0xffedb304>
>>> b()
150
>>> a = 45
>>> b()
135
```

EDIT: I have already respond at this kind of anwser here: [How to create recalculating variables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18064564/how-to-create-recalculating-variables-in-python/18064632#18064632)

## With a homemade class

Another way given on this same thread is to create an `Expression` class, and change the `repr` return.

> **Fair warning:** this is a hack only suitable for experimentation and play in a Python interpreter environment. Do not feed untrusted input into this code.

```
class Expression(object):
    def __init__(self, expression):
        self.expression = expression
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(eval(self.expression))
    def __str__(self):
        return str(eval(self.expression))


>>> a = 5
>>> b = Expression('a + 5')
>>> b
10
>>> a = 20
>>> b
25
```

Comment: Very cute, but quite a bit above the level of the question.., no?

Answer (score -1):

What do you thing of this way ? :

```
class XB(object):
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        try:
            return 3 * a
        except:
            return None


x = XB()

print 'x.b ==',x.b
a = 50
print 'x.b ==',x.b
a = 46
print 'x.b ==',x.b
```

return

```
x.b == None
x.b == 150
x.b == 138
```