# Python class-less property / descriptor?

Tags: python

I have no intention of actually *doing* this; I'm just wondering if it's possible. I suspect it isn't.

Is it possible in Python to make a variable that resolves to the result of a function call each time it's accessed, but without accessing it via an intermediary object? With a class I can do this:

```
class A:
    i = 0
    @property
    def data(self):
        self.i += 1
        return self.i

>>> a = A()
>>> a.data
1
>>> a.data
2
```

But is there some (however hacky) way I can eliminate the class?  ie:

```
i = 0
def func():
    global i
    i += 1
    return i
>>> data = some_magic_here(func)
>>> data
1
>>> data
2
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [defining python function without the brackets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698603/defining-python-function-without-the-brackets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

A plain variable is never behaving like a function in Python.
There might be some "magic/tricky" way to do it (by bypassing the normal restrictions), but that would be something called "monkey patching" -- some thing that is not seen positively in the Python community.